# Write C++ array to file, avoiding creating a std::string

Tags: c++

I have a struct representing ASCII data:

```
struct LineData
{
    char _asciiData[256];
    uint8_t _asciiDataLength;
}
```

created using:

```
std::string s = "some data here";
memcpy(obj._asciiData, s.length());
obj._asciiDataLength = s.length();
```

How do I write the char array to file as ASCII, in the lowest latency? I want to avoid the intermediary stage of creating a temporary `std::string`.

I tried:

```
file.write((char *)obj._asciiData, sizeof(obj._asciiDataLength));
file << std::endl;
```

but my file just contains '0' each line.

Comment: If you're just writing binary [`ostream.write`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write)

Comment: `sizeof(obj._asciiDataLength)` is wrong

Comment: @Mgetz I'm not writing binary, I'm writing ASCII but without strings?

Comment: then insofar as the `char` array is zero terminated you can just use `operator <<` to output it doesn't need a string?

Comment: Yes. Your `LineData` struct looks much like a `std::string`, except for the fixed buffer size. Why not keep it as a string in memory and only add the padding when saving to file?

Comment: You write memcpy(obj._asciiData, s.length()); shouldn't be something like memcpy(obj._asciiData, s.c_str(), s.length()); ? You might want to consider using strncpy http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `sizeof(obj._asciiDataLength)` is probably `1` on your system so only one character is written. You want the actual length, not the size of the `uint8_t`:

```
file.write(obj._asciiData, obj._asciiDataLength);
```

Comment: Also, the explicit cast is redundant.

Comment: @eerorika Right, I only focused on the faulty part but it is indeed redundant.

Comment: Technically insofar as `_asciiData` is zero terminated they should be able to just use `operator <<` too

Comment: @Mgetz Note how the OP creates that struct: `memcpy(obj._asciiData, s.length());`. Typo (the source is missing, I'd assume `s.c_str()`) apart, it uses [length()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size), not `length() + 1`.

Comment: @Bob__ I suspect we're seeing an odd snapshot where there are better ways of doing things. Hence the "insofar". I really don't think we have a clear picture.

Comment: @eerorika -- also, the "explicit" in "explicit cast" is redundant. <g> A cast is always explicit -- it's something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion. (Yes, I know, we're losing that meaning in less formal contexts than the standard itself, and many people think "cast" and "conversion" are synonyms. Sigh.)

Comment: @PeteBecker yeah. I was actually chuckling about the irony to myself earlier, but it was too late to edit the comment.